# Django 2.x - filter redirects based on relational database content

Tags: django

I have an app I am developing that has 2 types of user (A & B) and I have a page that I want to redirect users that are not authenticated and not type B. The user type is set in a relational database.

My two db tables for this are

`User - pk, etc...
 Profile - pk, uid (user pk), account_type`

**What I have done so far:**

I have already used `@login_required` in my `views.py` doc to verify authentication successfully.

I can filter for the content where pid is set manually:
`Profile.objects.filter(user__pk=1)`
And I can get the current user id with `request.user.id`

**What I am struggling with**

What I have attempted to do is create a conditional, where I am using the `request.user.id` with the filter to find that user and then verify account type. I am not sure how to pull the `account_type` and at this point my code is becoming a mess, and probably ineffective. I've searched for this, but everything I have found using the keywords I have here has revealed different problems than what I am trying to solve.

**Edited additional info**

I have 2 apps at use here, 1 is `accounts` one is `listings`, the page I am doing this for is for posting a listing, that is in the `listing` app; I only want one type of user (B) to be able to post it.

in the accounts I have this class:

```
class Profile(models.Model):
    user = models.OneToOneField(User, on_delete=models.CASCADE)
    location = models.CharField(max_length=30, blank=True)
    account_type = models.CharField(max_length=30)
```

In the listing app I have not yet created a relevant model, my understanding was that this filtering would happen in the view.

In the view I am doing:

```
@login_required
def post(request):
   current_user = request.user
   if : #here is where I want to filter, but haven't been able to get it to work

   else:
     return redirect('index')
```

Comment: Submit code for further understanding

Comment: Can you show us the models?

Comment: And queries that you are using?

Comment: Does every user have a profile? If so you should be able to do: `if user.profile.account_type != "B":`. Otherwise, you'll have to catch `UserProfile.DoesNotExist` and have a default behavior.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You will get the account type value directly as

```
account_type = request.user.profile.account_type
```

So, you could able to do the stuff according to the `account_type` value as below,

```
@login_required
def post(request):
    account_type = request.user.profile.account_type
    if account_type == "B"
       # do your stuff

    else:
        return redirect('index')
```

Answer (score 1):

Starting from your model design, if your system has the criteria that one user has only one profile. Then set uid in Profile model as OnetoOneField so that you can easily access account_type by `User.objects.filter(id=request.user.id).profile.account_type`.

Else, if your system has the criteria that one user can have multiple profile. Then you first need to access it profiles, and select the particular profile by adding more filter, then you access the account_type:

`User.objects.filter(id=request.user.id).profile_set.all()` gives you user's all profile.

`User.objects.filter(id=request.user.id).profile_set.get(your_filter)` gives you user's particular profile.

`User.objects.filter(id=request.user.id).profile_set.get(your_filter).account_type` gives you access to particular user's profile's account_type.

[One to One relationship description here](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/2.1/topics/db/examples/one_to_one/)

[Foreign (many to one) key description here](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/2.1/topics/db/examples/many_to_one/)